# How to extract the acronym specific for my data with UMLS

Tags: r, text-mining, medical

I am new to the [United Medical Language System](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/). I would like to annotate some text that gives reports about endoscopy examinations. The terminology is therefore specific to gastroenterology. Some of the text contains acronyms like `TI` which would mean terminal ileum. However according to UMLS TI also stands for a number of other terms that are non-gastroenterological. I would like to build a gastroenterology lexicon only from UMLS terms. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would make a 3 column dataframe : acronym, domain, meaning. The first two columns beeing the key to have the right meaning.

Comment: Is there a way of creating a custom lexicon from the UMLS data? Maybe this is the easiest way to go.....

Comment: There is packages in R about UMLS like `rUMLS`, you could try to install them and run the vignette to know what it is possible to do.